# PHP how to remove strings from a file

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a file named `test.txt` and i want to remove the lines from this file which have length of less than 30 characters and line starting with Capital letter word and ending with an dot or question mark should not be deleted.

For example content of test.txt file is:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
Long text.
text 4
Long text 2?
```

After filtering, result should be

```
Long text.
Long text 2?
```

```
 <?php


# create and load the HTML
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$tekst = file_get_html('http://www.naszawiedza.pl/')->plaintext;

foreach ($tekst as $key=>&$value) {
    if (strlen($value) > 60) {
        unset($yourArray[$key]);
    }
}

echo $tekst;

//kropka
    $string = $tekst;
    $substr = '.';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef

//znak zapytania
$string = $tekst;
    $substr = '?';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef
//podwójna spacja
$string = $tekst;
    $substr = '\r\n\r\n';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef

//Wykrzyknik
    $string = $tekst;
    $substr = '!';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef

//tabulator
    $string = $tekst;
    $substr = ' ';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef
    echo $newstring;





    // zmienna $dane, która będzie zapisana 
// może także pochodzić z formularza np. $dane = $_POST['dane']; 
$dane = $newstring; 

// przypisanie zmniennej $file nazwy pliku 
$file = "testy.txt"; 



// uchwyt pliku, otwarcie do dopisania 
$fp = fopen($file, "a"); 

// blokada pliku do zapisu 
flock($fp, 2); 

// zapisanie danych do pliku 
fwrite($fp, $dane); 

// odblokowanie pliku 
flock($fp, 3); 

// zamknięcie pliku 
fclose($fp); 








//usun puste wiersze
$plik = "testy.txt";

// odczyt
$bufor = array();
$fd = fopen($plik, "r");
while (!feof ($fd)) 
{
    $linia = fgets($fd, 1024);
    if(strlen(trim($linia)))
    {
        $bufor[] = $linia;
    }    
}
fclose($fd);

// zapis 
$fdw = fopen($plik, "w");
foreach($bufor as $wiersz)
{
    fwrite($fdw, $wiersz);
}
fclose($fdw);
```

Comment: Please provide more details what you exactly want to do and what you tried for it?

Comment: ** How to remove a line from file shorter than eg 20 signs. ** What does this line means? Update your question with the appropriate details and example

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Maybe you should read up about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Anyway, your problem can be broken down into three tasks: 1) Read the file. 2) Process the contents (filter). 3) Write processed contents to file. There is *plenty* of information available on 1 and 3, so you should be able to solve that yourself. I therefore assume your issue lies within the second step. I recommend you show us your code that handles the processing and edit your question to contain a specific question that relates to the code in question.

Comment: You just edited your question, but it is still lacking important information. First, what *is* the output you are getting? Or does it not work at all? If so, what happens? Error message? And, resulting from that, what is your actual question? Also, side note: I would recommend to code in English. It comes in handy when working in (international) teams or when seeking questions in an international community, like right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sample code that will do this thing

**test.txt contents:**

```
text 1
text 2
Long text.
text3
Long text 2?
Line with 30 characters ending with a question mark?
text4
```

```
<?php

$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

$i = 0;
$string = "";

while(!feof($file))
{
    // get the line
    $line = trim(fgets($file));

    // check if line have 30 characters
    if(strlen($line) > 30)
    {

        // get first character ascai value
        $value = ord(substr($line, 0, 1));

        // get the last character
        $last = substr($line, -1);

        // now check if it has allowed criteria
        if((($value >= 65 && $value <= 90) &&  ($last == '.' || $last == '?')))
        {
            $string .= $line."\n";
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);

// put the proccessed content back to file
file_put_contents("test.txt", trim($string));
?>
```

Ouput after executing code

```
Line with 30 characters ending with a question mark?
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I get output like that:


text 1 text 2 text 3 Long text. text 4 Long text 2?


its just should filter the shorter than 30 signs and must end with comma or question mark.

Comment: really? did u tried it i have tried this code and it is working fine

Comment: hm its good to start to work with, I got longer words so i get words longer than 30 signs without dots and questoin marks. If u'zpou can check this is how i use code from second answer

Comment: what? it will give u lines having more then 30 characters or which have starting character as an capital letter and ending with either . or ? .

Comment: I get lines with less than 30 characters. Just try code i posted in second answer and look what it gives. And i loose new line signs so there are everything in one line longer than 30 signs should also be filtered by comma or question mark.

Comment: i am not able to understand what exactly u need.

Comment: you only need lines starting with captial letter and ending with . or ? without checking its length???????????

Comment: The steps of program:

1. check if string is minimum 30 chars long if not delete

2. filter all strings which are not first capital letters and ended with comma or question mark if not delete


as autput i wanna just sentences longer than 30 chars and got capital and special char at the end

its simple parser

Comment: if you want any special character at the end you can update it easily by using the ASCII values.

Comment: now i get empty file but im working on it. It works on test data but not with file i want to filter. If you can run whole program i wrote maybe you can find error.

Comment: @thecgla this is simply not how SO works. Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If not, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Full program code. It gives me empty file. Should be here only sentences with more than 30 chars and with capital letter on beginning and question mark or dot at the end.

```
<?php


# create and load the HTML
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$tekst = file_get_html('http://www.naszawiedza.pl/')->plaintext;

foreach ($tekst as $key=>&$value) {
    if (strlen($value) > 60) {
        unset($yourArray[$key]);
    }
}

echo $tekst;

//kropka
    $string = $tekst;
    $substr = '.';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef

//znak zapytania
$string = $tekst;
    $substr = '?';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef
//podwójna spacja
$string = $tekst;
    $substr = '\r\n\r\n';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef

//Wykrzyknik
    $string = $tekst;
    $substr = '!';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef

//tabulator
    $string = $tekst;
    $substr = ' ';
    $attachment = "\r\n";
    //$position = strpos($string, 'a');
    $newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $string);
    // bca+++def a+++bcdef
    echo $newstring;





    // zmienna $dane, która będzie zapisana 
// może także pochodzić z formularza np. $dane = $_POST['dane']; 
$dane = $newstring; 

// przypisanie zmniennej $file nazwy pliku 
$file = "testy.txt"; 



// uchwyt pliku, otwarcie do dopisania 
$fp = fopen($file, "a"); 

// blokada pliku do zapisu 
flock($fp, 2); 

// zapisanie danych do pliku 
fwrite($fp, $dane); 

// odblokowanie pliku 
flock($fp, 3); 

// zamknięcie pliku 
fclose($fp); 

//usun puste wiersze
$plik = "testy.txt";

// odczyt
$bufor = array();
$fd = fopen($plik, "r");
while (!feof ($fd)) 
{
    $linia = fgets($fd, 1024);
    if(strlen(trim($linia)))
    {
        $bufor[] = $linia;
    }    
}
fclose($fd);

// zapis 
$fdw = fopen($plik, "w");
foreach($bufor as $wiersz)
{
    fwrite($fdw, $wiersz);
}
fclose($fdw);

$file = fopen("testy.txt", "r");

$i = 0;
$string = "";

while(!feof($file))
{
    // get the line
    $line = trim(fgets($file));

    // check if line have 30 characters
    if(strlen($line) > 30)
    {

        // get first character ascai value
        $value = ord(substr($line, 0, 1));

        // get the last character
        $last = substr($line, -1);

        // now check if it has allowed criteria
        if((($value >= 65 && $value <= 90) &&  ($last == '.' || $last == '?')))
        {
            $string .= $line."\n";
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);

// put the proccessed content back to file
file_put_contents("testy.txt", trim($string));
?>
```